# Joomla! displays the code of the template in a weird way

Tags: php, joomla

So, I'm using latest Joomla 3.2 and template I created. This is the code from index.php:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrap_to_r">
        <div id="w_main">
            <div id="w_content_wrapper" class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?> ">
                <div id="main_column">
                    <div id="logo"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="logo" style="xhtml" /></div>
                    <div id="content">
                        <jdoc:include type="message" />
                        <jdoc:include type="component" />
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content" style="xhtml" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar" style="xhtml" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="quote"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="quote" style="xhtml" /></div>
        <div id="w_footer">
            <div id="user1"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" /></div>
            <div id="user2"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml" /></div>
            <div id="user3"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" style="xhtml" /></div>
            <div id="user4"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" style="xhtml" /></div>
            <div id="copyright"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="copyright" style="xhtml" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cookie"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="cookie" style="xhtml" /></div>
<div id="additional"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="additional" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

The problem is, I created many category blogs and until yesterday they were all displaying correctly. But then I noticed than only one category blog is displaying totally incorrectly. What happenes is that

```
<div id="sidebar"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

displays INSIDE

```
<div id="content">
    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content" style="xhtml" />
</div>
```

so I get something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
    <div id="sidebar"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar" style="xhtml" /></div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content" style="xhtml" />
</div>
```

This is part of the code from Chrome browser:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXNqctc_x5dVUVwNXJ1NUlyNkU/edit?usp=sharing

I'm completely out of ideas here. I tried reuploading template, I created new menu items linked to this specific category blog. Problem doesn't go away. There is no problem with other blogs or if I just change the category of the blog inside same menu item. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla blogs take the first part of the article up until the "**readmore**" separator.

Sometimes the **readmore** separator is placed in the editor inside a `div`, thus the intro Joomla extracts contains an unbalanced open `<div` which destroys your layout.   The browser does the rest of the issue trying to balance the open `<div` with the first corrensponding `</div` and ignoring the extra open `div` in the text.

Find the first item in the blog that displays wrong, open in the editor and place the readmore in the right place. You might have to clean the cache before you see the results.

Comment: There definitely is a problem with Readmore. However, I couldn't find the opened <div . I have found the Readmore causing the truble and I removed the article and created new one. Seems like it's working now! Thanks!

Comment: What may have happened is that somehow you split a div so that the open was before the readmore and the close was after it (and thus not displaying).